# Flutter/Dart: Concurrent Modification Exception without changing list elements

Tags: list, flutter, dart

During testing and debugging of an app, i noticed there was an Exception that mostly happens during debug testing only, inside a for-loop that iterates over a list:

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'.`

I have searched around and found that it mostly happens if you change the list itself during the iteration, but i cannot see where it happens in the code:

Main function:

```
static Future<void> save(EntryModel entry) async {
    ...
      List<TagModel> tagsList = entry.tags;
      List<int> tagIdsInserted = [];
      if (tagsList != null && tagsList.isNotEmpty) {
        for (TagModel tag in tagsList) {

          //Error happens inside this loop
          int tagIdInserted = await TagContract.save(tag); //this function does not alter the tag in any way.

          if (tagIdInserted == null || tagIdInserted <= 0) {
            throw Exception('Invalid TagID!');
          }
          tagIdsInserted.add(tagIdInserted);
        }
      }
```

What happen is during the first iteration it runs fine, but the second or third one the `List<TagModel> tagsList` suddenly becomes empty, including from the initial object (the `entry` passed to the function).

Also i noticed that during runs without debugging it runs mostly fine, but i am not sure if that is because i am not catching the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does TagModel hold a reference to its EntryModel? What does TagContract do on save? Is there some Model manager that may be clearing an EntryModel's tags? There's not enough information to troubleshoot the issue. You'll have to use the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: @hola No, the TagModel does not contain any references to the Entry. The TagContract records the TagModel information on an SQLite database. I tried to debug the code, and i noticed that on the second or third loop iteration the EntryModel clears its reference to the TagModel list for some reason. I still have no ideia what could be the origin of the problem, but First_Strike answer seems to clarify some of the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using `await` inside a loop, it is just too dangerous.

You have to understand how asynchronous code execute. If an `await` is encountered and the `Future` is unable to return synchronously, the runtime will suspend the execution of this function and jump to whatever other jobs that are on the top of the queue.

So when the `await` is encountered, the runtime will start executing some god-knows-where code and those code touched your `tagsList`.

Try to understand the following example. This will directly triggers the exception.

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> ids = [1,2,3];
  test(ids);
  ids.add(1); // If the async function get suspended, this becomes the top of the queue.
}

void test(List<int> ids) async {
  for (final id in ids) {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
  }
}
```

In async programming, avoid writing an `await` who depends on exposed shared states.

For a list of async tasks, always prepare them in an `Iterable<Future>`, then use `Future.wait` to synchronize them and get the result in a single `await`.

For your code

```dart
final results = await Future.wait(tagsList.map((tag)=>TagContract.save(tag)))
```

Comment: I tested the code with your suggestion. So far it seems to be working, but i am still not sure if that was the root of the problem. I will search around the documentation for how Futures work, but thanks for the advice nonetheless.

Comment: Dart's `Future` works in the same way as Javascript's `Promise`. You can refer to both documentations. It's better to prepare and use local state before an `await`, because `await` means "at here runtime scheduler may execute arbitrary other tasks in order to wait"